# Equivalent of 'ps' for Windows CE?

Tags: command-line, process, telnet, windows-ce

What is the equivalent of 'ps' (that is, a command which shows the running process list) command in Linux, for Windows CE (whose command-line, I'm accessing through telnet)?

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Power Toys for CE](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10601), use RAPI debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PSList.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) from Sysinternals.  It can give you a list for the local computer or a remote system.    I've no idea if it will work on WinCE systems, but it's not very large and shouldn't take long to try out.

```
C:\> pslist /?

Usage: pslist.exe [-d][-m][-x][-t][-s [n] [-r n] [\\computer [-u username][-p password][name|pid]
   -d          Show thread detail.
   -m          Show memory detail.
   -x          Show processes, memory information and threads.
   -t          Show process tree.
   -s [n]      Run in task-manager mode, for optional seconds specified.
               Press Escape to abort.
   -r n        Task-manager mode refresh rate in seconds (default is 1).
   \\computer  Specifies remote computer.
   -u          Optional user name for remote login.
   -p          Optional password for remote login. If you don't present
               on the command line pslist will prompt you for it if necessary.
   name        Show information about specified process.
   pid         Show information about specified process.
```

Comment: Tried this but; it says 'cannot execute pslist.EXE' when I enter 'pslist' or 'pslist.exe' as command (and yes, I'm in the directory where I copied the files).

Comment: you could try using the full path (eg `\path\to\pslist.exe`) but honestly it sounds like you'd need a version specially compiled for WinCE.  sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Type in `kill` - this will list the processes by name and their PID - then type `kill *PID*` (where PID is the actual PID) and it will then terminate the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *shell.exe* file in /Windows, you can run:

```
\Windows> shell.exe -c gi proc
```

It is a very common file which you can find in Windows CE because it is used to debug remotely.

Answer (score -3):

From the commandline, type: TASKLIST
(Uppercase, lowercase, doesn't matter. It's not Unix...)

Add /? to get an overview of commandline options.

Tested this with Vista, don't know if it's available on XP and lower...

---

Oops... Windows CE, you say? That's the Windows version for mobile devices. I wonder if it allows the same command but I don't think so.

Comment: The request is for Windows CE, not the desktop Windows.

Comment: @Snark, I've already pointed that out. However, commands for Windows XP/Vista might also work for CE...